# Redmine with s3 plugin can't deploy on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, redmine

I have Redmine 2.5 already deployed on Heroku.
I am trying to install amazon s3 plugin. I am using this gem: https://github.com/ka8725/redmine_s3
I have installed the plugin looking the official doc.

`Bundle` and `bundle install` work fine in my local machine.

When I push in heroku I have this error:

```
$ git push heroku master:master                                                                       
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 730 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.1
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.5.2
       Running: bundle install --without sqlite --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * aws-sdk
       Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * aws-sdk
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I have try to re-run `bundle install` but the problem is not solved. The Gemfile.lock is already in my git version control system.
The aws-sdk gem is installed by the plugin.

Comment: How has the s3 plugin worked with your 2.5 version of Redmine now that some time has gone by?

Comment: It works fine, I am using it since july without problems but I don't have a massive utilization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use this plugin on Heroku, you will have to remove the 'plugins' folder from the .gitignore file, and remove the '.git' folder in the plugin before pushing your commit to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run `bundle update` and is `Gemfile.lock` in your `.gitignore` (it shouldn't be). When you set your gems the specific configuration you use gets added to your `Gemfile.lock` so that you have a consistent deployment and gem versions don't change. The error there is saying that your `Gemfile.lock` is outdated see [here for more details](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update/).